# Нужны ли здесь кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки в данном вопросе?

> Что значит («)где мы(»)?

Фраза является ответом на вопрос: «Где мы?»

Answer (score 2):

Лучше избежать цитирования при наличии там вопроса, т. к. обозначить общую вопросительную интонацию практически невозможно.

Правильнее будет обойтись тире: *«Что значит — где мы?»*

Comment: Благодарю. А вот если такая, например, реплика: "Мне не нравится слово "пока". В реплике, ответом на которую является данная фраза, представим, слово "пока" тоже фигурировало. В этом случае уместны кавычки?

Comment: Кавычек и здесь избежать можно, выделив слово курсивом, Bold,  или тем и другим, а также разрядкой: «слово  п о к а».

Comment: @shampar Действительно, вариант с тире широко употребляется (есть и в Нацкорпусе). Но как его объяснить формально?

Comment: Возможность «сложения двух вопросов», при одном знаке вопроса на выходе, наверное существовала бы, если бы цитата шла впереди. Но при таком порядке фразы её (возможности) нет.

Comment: Дело не в том, что два вопроса. См: "И Танзиля сказала ментам, что дверь вчера она закрыла ― Постой, Вик, что значит ― закрыла?" [Марина Зосимкина. Ты проснешься. Книга первая (2015)]

Comment: Здесь не два вопроса и, как вариант, почему бы не быть кавычкам,  при этом знак вопроса остался бы вне их: что значит ― «закрыла»?

Comment: Меня интересует именно тире: как его обосновать во всех вариантах.

Comment: Тождество, пауза, пара тире — по границам вводного оборота, замена подразумевающегося слова (Что значит вопрос: «где мы»? Что значит твоё «где мы»?).